# Code working on MySQL Workbench but not in liveSQL by oracle

Tags: mysql

I'm creating a DB with 2 tables.

When I run the code in MySQL Workbench it works but when I run it in Oracle's liveSQL (I'm not posting a link because I don't think it is permitted) it doesn't.

The script is:

```
CREATE TABLE supervisores (
supid       INT(6) NOT NULL,
suparea     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
supnombre   VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
supemail    VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (supid)
);

CREATE TABLE nomina (
empid       INT(6) NOT NULL,
empnombre   VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
empedad     INT(2) NOT NULL,
emparea     VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
supid       INT(6),
PRIMARY KEY (empid),
FOREIGN KEY (supid) REFERENCES supervisores (stupid)
);

INSERT INTO supervisors
VALUES
(100001, 'Ventas', 'Jaime Rodriguez', 'jrodriguz@empresa.com'),
(100002, 'IT', 'Camila Jimenez', 'cjimenez@empresa.com'),
(100003, 'Operaciones', 'Diana Delgado', 'ddelgado@empresa.com'),
(100004, 'RRHH', 'Ana Silgado', 'asilgado@empresa.com'),
(100005, 'IT', 'Pepito perez', 'cjimenez@empresa.com');

INSERT INTO nomina
VALUES 
(106218, 'Jairo Caldera', 32, 'Ventas', 100001),
(107773, 'Carlos Saldarriaga', 31, 'IT', 100005),
(102801, 'Javier Zúñiga', 25, 'Operaciones', 100003),
(101845, 'Julian Hurtado', 27, 'RRHH', 100004),
(105358, 'Viviana Solano', 28, 'RRHH', 100004),
(101351, 'Karen Castillo', 35, 'Operaciones', 100003),
(104278, 'Sebastián Paternina', 42, 'IT', 100002),
(105377, 'Marina Álvarez', 19, 'IT', 100002),
(105002, 'Ricardo Colorado', 28, 'Operaciones', 100003),
(100178, 'Andrés Domínguez', 35, 'Operaciones', 100003),
(103710, 'Daniel Olaya', 22, 'Operaciones', 100003),
(101499, 'Crisrina Navarrete', 24, 'Operaciones', 100003);

SELECT empnombre, empedad, empid, emparea, supnombre, supemail
FROM supervisores, nomina
WHERE supervisores.supid = nomina.supid
ORDER BY empnombre;
```

RESULT IN MySQL Workbench:

[MySQL Workbench](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wHxbj.png)

RESULT IN Oracle's LiveSQL:

```
ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You cannot just dump mysql into oracle and expect it to work..for example oracle does not allow int(6) also primary key on supervisores  is misspelled.That's not how you bulk insert to oracle and the code is riddled with spelling misstakes.

Comment: i know there are differences. I'm asking because I want to learn those differences.
Misspelling corrected.